# Reusing same JPanel in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have two JPanels that needs to add a JPanel into it, however only the last added JPanel does it show the JPanel. As shown below:

```
holderPanel1.add(dataPanel);
holderPanel2.add(dataPanel);
```

only holderPanel2 shows the dataPanel, but holderPanel1 does not show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UI Components (such as JPanel) are the underline representation of things you see on the screen (location, parent, sub-components etc.), so each panel that you see on the screen has to have a separate underline representation, so you cannot add a panel to two different panels, you need to create two separate panels.

Comment: is it possible to create another JPanel? i have tried dataPanel2 = dataPanel; but it would not work

Comment: You can create another panel, but what you did (in comment) is assigning the same panel to another variable. You need to create another panel using `JPanel p2 = new JPanel()`

Comment: then does it mean i will have to create all components again to add in the new JPanel. wouldn't this be bad if i need to use the JPanel more than twice.

Comment: If those are two separate panels (as they lay in two separate panels) that's what you need to do. Consider creating a class that extends JPanel, and include all those inner components and instantiate it twice.

Comment: _extends JPanel, and include all those inner_ - not a good reason for subclassing, adding stuff is the core functionality of a container, nothing special. Instead, implement a factory doing the panel building and call it twice :-)